# Why is this ALSA configuration file preventing aplay and arecord from listing PCM devices?

Tags: linux, audio, embedded, alsa

In my embedded system I have this configuration file in `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
pcm_slave.sl2 {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        rate 48000
        channels 2
        format S16_LE
}

pcm.rate_convert {
        type plug
        slave sl2
}

pcm.!default rate_convert
```

I noticed that since this file was placed in the system, `aplay -L` and `arecord -L` cannot list the PCM devices anymore. `aplay -l` and `arecord -l` are instead working as expected.

If this file is not placed in there, the list is correctly returned. What is this doing exactly? Why is this preventing `aplay` and `arecord` from listing PCM devices?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Vladimir's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330502), I set this specifically in my `/etc/asound.conf` file:

```
defaults.namehint.showall on
defaults.namehint.extended on
```

Alternatively, add a `hint` to your custom pcm control device:

```
pcm.rate_convert {
        # snip
        hint.description "Describe your device here"
}
```

I haven't yet found documentation on this, but you can find an example in

- `alsa.conf` on your system (I have it in `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`)
- `alsa.conf` in the [alsa GitHub repo](https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/blob/9122992a91334cd188203deba54cc077a91cd475/src/conf/alsa.conf#L55)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the `defaults.namehint.showall` and `defaults.namehint.extended` are set to on in the `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

from `man aplay`:

> ```
>   -l, --list-devices
>           List all soundcards and digital audio devices
>
>    -L, --list-pcms
>           List all PCMs defined
> ```

from ALSA wiki:

> A PCM device is something like an abstract soundcard. It can either be
>   a hardware device or a PCM plugin layer device. See the alsa-lib
>   documentation for more info. See the .asoundrc and the dmix page for
>   uses of this abstraction layer.

.asoundrc is ALSA configuration file used in user home folder instead of system folder /etc/asound.conf. either of these files can reconfigure PCM
https://alsa.opensrc.org/Asoundrc